# The need for $1 and $2 for comparison with an here-string

Tags: bash, variable, control-flow, case, here-string

This is a follow up to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/483587/read-verification-alternative-two-prompts-and-if-then-comparison-alternative);
I don't know why but I keep misunderstanding the following code, although I try very hard to understand it:

```
function read_and_verify  {
    read -p "$1:" tmp1
    read -p "$2:" tmp2
    if [ "$tmp1" != "$tmp2" ]; then
        echo "Values unmatched. Please try again."; return 2
    else
        read "$1" <<< "$tmp1"
    fi
}

read_and_verify domain "Please enter the domain of your web application twice" 
read_and_verify dbrootp "Please enter the app DB root password twice" 
read_and_verify dbuserp "Please enter the app DB user password twice"
```

I misunderstand why is the `$1` and `$2` needed and henceforth why is the `read "$1" <<< "$tmp1"` needed.

What is actually happening in this comparison scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read -p "$1:" tmp1` and `read -p "$2:" tmp2` read a line of input from the user each, using the first (`$1`) and second (`$2`) arguments to the function as prompts. The results are stored in `tmp1` and `tmp2`. Then, if they are equal, the value from `tmp1` is read into a variable named by the function's first argument with `read "$1" <<< "$tmp1"`

So, what you get with `read_and_verify domain "Please enter the domain of your web application twice"` is something that looks like this, with the user's input in italics:

```
domain:foo
Please enter the domain of your web application twice:foo
```

And then, the value entered is stored in the variable `domain`; running `echo "$domain"` after the above shows `foo`.

> I misunderstand why is the $1 and $2 needed and henceforth why is the read "$1" <<< "$tmp1" needed.

`$1` and `$2` are used as prompts to the user, and `$1` is *also* used to pass the name of the result variable to the function. This makes the first prompt a bit odd. It might be better to use something more descriptive, e.g.:

```
read -p "Please enter value for '$1': " tmp1
read -p "Please repeat the value to verify: " tmp2
```

Or to use the message passed in `$2` for both prompts like the [answer to your other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/483730/170373) does.

`read "$1" <<< "$tmp1"` is also somewhat odd, in that usually you'd be able to just assign the value from one variable to another. Here, though, the problem is that `$1` contains the *name* of a variable, so we need an indirect assignment. In Bash 4.3 and later, we could use a name reference for that:

```
declare -n ref="$1"
ref=$tmp1
```

So, the whole function might be better written like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
function read_and_verify  {
    read -p "Please enter value for '$1': " tmp1
    read -p "Please repeat the value to verify: " tmp2
    if [ "$tmp1" != "$tmp2" ]; then
        echo "Values unmatched. Please try again."; return 2
    else
        declare -n ref="$1"
        ref=$tmp1
    fi
}
```

(note that this doesn't use the second argument.)

Answer (score 0):

`read_and_verify` is a function, in that context `$1` is the first argument (here you invoke it with one of domain, dbrootp or dbuserp) and `$2` is the second argument (the strings following each of those options in the invocations). If we expand it for invocation one:

```
function read_and_verify  {
    read -p "domain:" tmp1
    read -p "Please enter the domain of your web application twice:" tmp2
    if [ "$tmp1" != "$tmp2" ]; then
        echo "Values unmatched. Please try again."; return 2
    else
        read "domain" <<< "$tmp1"
    fi
}
```

And that is what `$1` and `$2` are doing in your function.