# What is "declare" in Bash?

Tags: bash, function, shell-builtin, control-flow, declare

After reading ilkkachu's answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/510193/the-need-for-1-and-2-for-comparison-with-an-here-string) I learned on the existence of the `declare` (with argument `-n`) shell built in.

`help declare` brings:

> Set variable values and attributes.
>
> Declare variables and give them attributes. If no NAMEs are given,
> display the attributes and values of all variables.

> -n ... make NAME a reference to the variable named by its value

I ask for a general explanation with an example regarding `declare` because I don't understand the `man`. I know what is a variable and expanding it but I still miss the `man` on `declare` (variable attribute?).

Maybe you'd like to explain this based on the code by ilkkachu in the answer:

```
#!/bin/bash
function read_and_verify  {
    read -p "Please enter value for '$1': " tmp1
    read -p "Please repeat the value to verify: " tmp2
    if [ "$tmp1" != "$tmp2" ]; then
        echo "Values unmatched. Please try again."; return 2
    else
        declare -n ref="$1"
        ref=$tmp1
    fi
}
```

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/522366/what-is-a-variable-attribute

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In most cases it is enough with an implicit declaration in `bash`

```
asdf="some text"
```

But, sometimes you want a variable's value to only be integer (so in case it would later change, even automatically, it could only be changed to an integer, defaults to zero in some cases), and can use:

```
declare -i num
```

or

```
declare -i num=15
```

Sometimes you want arrays, and then you need `declare`

```
declare -a asdf   # indexed type
```

or

```
declare -A asdf   # associative type
```

You can find good tutorials about arrays in `bash` when you browse the internet with the search string 'bash array tutorial' (without quotes), for example

[linuxconfig.org/how-to-use-arrays-in-bash-script](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-use-arrays-in-bash-script)

---

I think these are the most common cases when you declare variables.

---

Please notice also, that

- in a function, `declare` makes the variable local (in the function)
- without any name, it lists all variables (in the active shell)

  ```
  declare
  ```

Finally, you get a brief summary of the features of the shell built-in command `declare` in `bash` with the command

```
help declare
```

Answer (score 23):

The output of `help declare` is quite terse. A clearer explanation can be be found in `man bash` or `info bash` — the latter being the source for what follows.

First, some definitions. About [variables and attributes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters):

> A *parameter* is an entity that stores values. ... A *variable* is a parameter denoted by a `name`. A variable has a *value* and zero or more *attributes*. Attributes are assigned using the `declare` builtin command ...

And about the `declare` [builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins):

> **`declare`**
>
> ```bash
> declare [-aAfFgilnrtux] [-p] [name[=value] …]
> ```
>
> Declare variables and give them attributes. If no names are given, then display the values of variables instead.
>
> ...
>
> `-n`
> Give each *name* the *nameref* attribute, making it a name reference to another variable. That other variable is defined by the value of *name*. All references, assignments, and attribute modifications to *name*, except for those using or changing the `-n` attribute itself, are performed on the variable referenced by *name*’s value. ...

Note that *name reference* variables are only available in Bash 4.3 or later<sup>1</sup>.

Also, for a useful introduction to `declare` and variable attributes in Bash I would point you to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/381782/315749) to "What do `declare name` and `declare -g` do?
" (which mainly focuses on variables' scope, though).

---

Basically<sup>2</sup>, `declare name=[value]` is equivalent to the assignment `name=[value]` you are probably familiar with. In both cases, `name` is assigned the null value if `value` is missing.

Note that the slightly different `declare name`, instead, does not *set* the variable `name`<sup>3</sup>:

```bash
$ declare name

## With the -p option, declare is used to display
## attributes and values of variables
$ declare -p name
declare -- name            ## "name" exists

## Parameter expansion can be used to reveal if a variable is set:
## "isunset" is substituted to "name" only if unset 
$ echo "${name-isunset}"
isunset
```

Thus, the variable `name` can be:

- *declared* and *unset*, after `declare name`;
- *declared* and *set* with *null* as value, after `name=` or `declare name=`;
- *declared*, *set* and with a *non null* value after `name=value` or `declare name=value`.

More generally, `declare [options] name=value`

1. creates the variable `name` — which is a parameter with a name, which in turn is just a portion of memory you can use to store information<sup>4</sup>;
2. assigns the value `value` to it;
3. optionally sets `name`'s attributes, which define both the kind of value it can store (not in terms of a *type*, strictly speaking, since Bash's language is not typed) and the ways it can be manipulated.

Attributes are probably easier to explain with an example: using `declare -i name` will set the "integer" attribute of `name`, letting it be treated as an integer; quoting the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins), "arithmetic evaluation will be performed when the variable is assigned a value":

```bash
## Let's compare an ordinary variable with an integer
$ declare var
$ declare -i int
$ var="1+1"
$ int="1+1"
$ echo "$var"
1+1                 ## The literal "1+1"
$ echo "$int"
2                   ## The result of the evaluation of 1+1
```

---

In light of the above, what is happening in ilkkachu's code is that:

1. A variable named `ref` is declared, with the "nameref" attribute set, and the content of `$1` (the first positional argument) is assigned to it:

   ```bash
   declare -n ref="$1"
   ```

   The aim of a name reference variable such as `ref` is to hold the name of another variable, which would generally not be known in advance, possibly because we want it to be dynamically defined (e.g. because we want to reuse a piece of code and have it applied to several variables), and to provide a convenient way for referring to (and manipulating) it. (Not the only one, though: indirection is an alternative; see [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)).
2. When the value of the variable `tmp1` is assigned to `ref`:

   ```bash
   ref=$tmp1
   ```

   an additional variable, whose name is the value of `ref`, is implicitly declared. The value of `tmp1` is also *indirectly* assigned to the implicitly declared variable by means of this explicit assignment to `ref`.

In the context of [your linked question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/510193/315749), calling `read_and_verify` as

```bash
read_and_verify domain "Prompt text here..."
```

will declare the variable `domain` and assign it the value of `tmp1` (i.e. the user's input). It is exactly designed to reuse the code that interacts with the user and leverage a nameref variable to declare `domain` and a few other variables.

To take a closer look at the implicit part we can reproduce the process step by step:

```bash
## Assign a value to the first positional argument
$ set -- "domain"

## Declare the same "tmp1" variable as in your code
$ tmp1="value for domain"

## Declare a "ref" variable with the nameref attribute set and
## assign the value "domain" to it
$ declare -n ref="$1"

## Note that there is no "domain" variable yet
$ declare -p domain
bash: declare: domain: not found

## Assign a value to "ref" and, indirectly, to the "domain" variable
## that is implicitly declared  
$ ref=$tmp1

## Verify that a variable named "domain" now exists, and that
## its value is that of "tmp1"
$ declare -p domain
declare -- domain="value for domain"

## Verify that "ref" is actually a reference to "domain"
$ domain="new value"
$ echo "$domain"
new value
$ declare -p ref
declare -n ref="domain"
$ echo "$ref"
new value
```

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Reference: [CHANGES](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES?h=bash-4.3-alpha) file, section "3.  New Features in Bash", point "w".

This may be relevant: for instance, CentOS Linux 7.6 (currently the latest version) [is shipped with Bash 4.2](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.6.1810/os/x86_64/Packages/).</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>As usual with shell builtins, an exhaustive *and* concise explanation is elusive since they perform various, possibly heterogeneous actions. I will focus on declaring, assigning and setting attributes only, and I will consider listing, scoping and removing attributes as out of the scope of this answer.</sub>

<sup>3</sup> <sub>This behavior of `declare -p` has been introduced in Bash 4.4. Reference: [CHANGES](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES?h=bash-4.4-alpha) file, section "3.  New Features in Bash", point "f".

As [G-Man](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/80216/g-man) pointed out in comments, in Bash 4.3 `declare name; declare -p name` yields an error. But you can still check that `name` exists with `declare -p | grep 'declare -- name'`.</sub>

<sup>4</sup> <sub>FullBashGuide, [*Parameters*](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/FullBashGuide#Parameters) on mywiki.wooledge.org</sub>

Comment: (1) I can’t reproduce the results you show in your first code block: `declare name` followed by `declare -p name` yields “bash: declare: name: not found”.  (Although `declare -p | grep na` yields `declare -- name`.) (2) I believe that it’s a little bit misleading to present `echo "${name-isunset}"` in the context of `declare name`, inasmuch as it treats an *undeclared* (i.e., undefined) variable the same as a *declared* but *unset* variable. (3) You might want to mention that namerefs are available only in bash version 4.3 and higher.

Comment: @G-Man Thank you for your remarks! I'll address them as soon as I can and I'll update my answer where appropriate. As for (1), my `GNU bash, version 5.0.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` on Arch Linux still yields the results I showed. Maybe that behavior has been introduced only recently, I'll investigate that.

Comment: Yeah; I'm only using version 4.3.

Comment: @G-Man Answer updated with notes about (1) and (3). About (2): I aimed to illustrate that `declare x` doesn't set `x`, while `declare x=` does. I couldn't find any reference to back the assertion that `declare -- x` (as output of `declare -p x`) means "not set", while `declare -- x=""` means "set"; thus I brought in the `${parameter-word}` expansion, even if it cannot discriminate between "unset" and "doesn't exist", as you point out. I'm not sure how can I clarify this in my answer (without distracting the reader from the point), though.

Answer (score 21):

I’ll have my go at trying and explain this, but forgive me if I won’t follow the example you provided. I’ll rather try to guide you along my own, different, approach.

You say you already understand concepts such as “variables” and “expanding them”, etc. so I’ll just skim over some background knowledge that would otherwise require deeper focus.

So I’ll start by saying that, at its most **basic** level, the `declare` command is just a way for you to tell Bash that you need a variable value (i.e. a value the might change during script execution), and that you will refer to that value using a specific name, precisely the name you indicate next to the `declare` command itself.

That is:

```bsh
declare foo="bar"
```

tells Bash that you want the variable named `foo` have the value `bar`.

But.. hold on a minute.. we can do that without using `declare` at all, can’t we. As in:

```bsh
foo="bar"
```

Very true.

Well, it so happens that the above simple assignment is actually an **implicit** way for.. in fact.. declaring a variable.

(*It also so happens that the above is **one** of a few ways to **change** the value of the variable named `foo`; indeed it is precisely the most direct, concise, evident, straight-forward way.. but it’s not the only one.. .. I’ll come back to this later..*).

But then, if it is so well possible to declare a “name that will tag variable values” (just “variable” from hereafter, for the sake of brevity) without using `declare` at all, why would you ever want to use this pompous “declare” command ?

The answer lies in the fact that the above implicit way to declare a variable (`foo="bar"`), it.. implicitly.. makes Bash consider that variable of being of the type that is most commonly used in the typical usage scenario for a shell.

Such type is the string type, i.e. a sequence of characters with no particular meaning. Therefore a string is what you get when you use the implicit declaration.

But you, as the programmer, sometimes need to rather consider a variable as, e.g., a number.. on which you need to do arithmetic operations.. and using an implicit declaration like `foo=5+6` *won’t* make Bash assign value 11 to `foo` as you might expect. It will rather assign to `foo` the sequence of the three characters `5` `+` `6`.

So.. you need a way to tell Bash that you want `foo` to be considered a number, not a string.. and that’s what an explicit `declare` comes useful for.

Just say:

```bsh
declare -i foo=5+6  # <<- note the '-i' option: it means 'integer'
```

and Bash will happily do the math for you, and assign the *numeric* value 11 to variable `foo`.

That is: by saying `declare -i foo` you give to variable `foo` the *attribute* of being an integer number.

Declaring numbers (precisely integers, because Bash still does not understand decimals, floating points, and all that) may be the first reason for using `declare`, but it’s not the only reason. As you have already understood, there are a few other attributes you can give to variables. For instance you can have Bash to always make a variable’s value uppercase no matter what: if you say `declare -u foo`, then from then on when you say `foo=bar` Bash actually assigns the string `BAR` to the variable `foo`.

In order to give any of these attributes to a variable, you *must* use the `declare` command, there’s no other choice.

---

Now, one other of the attributes you can give through `declare` is the infamous “name-ref” one, the `-n` attribute. (*And now I'm going to resume the concept I put on hold earlier*).

The name-ref attribute, basically, allows Bash programmers for another way to change the value of a variable. It more precisely gives an *indirect* way to do that.

Here’s **how** it works:

You `declare` a variable having the `-n` attribute, and it is *very* recommended (though not strictly required, but it makes things simpler) that you also give a value to *this* very variable on the same `declare` command. Like this:

```bsh
declare -n baz="foo"
```

This tells Bash that, from then on, each time you will use, or change, the value of the variable named `baz`, it shall actually use, or change, the value of the variable named `foo`.

Which means that, from then on, you can say something like `baz=10+3` to make `foo` get the value of 13. Assuming of course that `foo` was previously declared as integer (`declare -i`) like we did just one minute ago, otherwise it’ll get the sequence of the four characters `1` `0` `+` `3`.

Also: if you change `foo`’s value directly, as in `foo=15`, you will see 15 also by saying `echo “${baz}”`. This is because variable `baz` declared as name-ref of `foo` always reflects `foo`’s value.

The above `declare -n` command is said a “name-reference” because it makes variable `baz` *refer* to the *name* of another variable. In fact we have declared `baz` has having value "foo" which, because of the `-n` option, is handled by Bash as the name for another variable.

Now, **why** on Earth would you ever want to do that ?

Well.. it’s worth saying that this is a feature for quite advanced needs.

In fact so advanced that when a programmer faces a problem that would really require a name-ref, it is also likely that such problem should rather be addressed to by using a proper programming language instead of Bash.

One of those advanced needs is, for instance, when you, as the programmer, cannot know during development *which* variable you will have to use in a specific point of a script, but it *will* be fully known dynamically at run-time. And given that there’s no way for any programmer to intervene at run-time, the only option is to make provision  *beforehand* for such situation in the script, and a “name-ref” can be the only viable way. As a widely known use case of this advanced need, think of plug-ins, for instance. The programmer of a “plugin-able” program needs to make generic provision for future (and possibly third-party) plug-ins beforehand. Therefore the programmer will need to use facilities like a name-ref in Bash.

One other advanced need is when you have to deal with huge amount of data *in RAM and* you also need to pass that data around functions of your script that *also* have to modify that data along the way. In such case you could certainly *copy* that data from one function to another (like Bash does when you do `dest_var="${src_var}"` or when you invoke functions like in `myfunc "${src_var}"`), but being that data a huge amount it would make for a huge waste of RAM *and* for a very inefficient operation. So The Solution if such situations arise is to use not a copy of the data, but a *reference* to that data. In Bash, a name-ref. This use case is really the norm in any modern programming language, but it is quite exceptional when it comes to Bash, because Bash is mostly designed for short simple scripts that mostly deal with files and external commands and thus Bash scripts seldom have to pass huge amount of data between functions. And when a script’s functions do need to share some data (access it and modify it) this is usually achieved by just using a global variable, which is quite the norm in Bash scripts as much as it is *very* deprecated in proper programming languages.

Then, there may be a notable use case for name-refs in Bash, and (maybe ironically) it is associated to when you use yet other types of variables:

1. variables that are declared as “indexed arrays” (`declare -a`)
2. variables that are declared as “associative arrays” (`declare -A`).

These are a type of variables that may be *more easily* (as well as more efficiently) passed along functions by using name-refs instead of by normal copying, even when they don’t carry huge amounts of data.

If all these examples sound weird, and still incomprehensible, it’s only because name-refs are indeed an advanced topic, and a rare need for the typical usage scenario of Bash.

I could tell you about occasions on which I for one have found use for name-refs in Bash, but so far they have been mostly for quite “esoteric” and complicated needs, and I’m afraid that if I described them I would only complicate things for you at this point of your learning. Just to mention the least complex (and possibly not esoteric): returning values from functions. Bash does not really support this functionality, so I obtained the same by using name-refs. This, incidentally, is exactly what your example code does.

---

Besides this, a small personal advice, which would actually be better suited for a comment but I haven't been able to condense it enough to fit into StackExchange's comment's limits.

I think that *the most* you should do at the moment is to just experiment with name-refs by using the simple examples I showed and maybe with the example code you provided, disregarding for the moment the “why on earth” part and focusing only on the “how it works” part. By experimenting a bit, the “how” part may sink better into your mind, so that the “why” part will come clear to you in due time when (or if) you’ll have a real practical problem for which a name-ref would truly come in handy.

Comment: LL3 I like your answer very much and I thumbed up: I finally understand what declare does --- not declaring variables but declaring their attributes; yet sadly I lost track when you started to explain what is a name-ref. I got no idea what it does and why to use it.

Comment: That is - why would one give this attribute

Comment: @JohnDoea I see. Maybe you might just leave this topic for the moment. It’s probably too soon to grasp this concept at the current point of your learning. Anyways I’ve expanded my answer with more examples and also a little personal addendum as to how I think you should proceed. I’ve also put horizontal lines to delimit the general explanation of `declare` from the specific explanation of `-n` from the personal addendum. I’ve also done a bit of rewording here and there but nothing substantial, so I think you may just re-read the `-n` part plus the little addendum.

Comment: Thank you, I think it's okay for me to learn on this right now, I just need an explanation I can understand and I should re-read your entire answer today, I'm here around.

Comment: You mention ``foo="bar"`` and ``declare foo="bar"``.  You might want to mention (if only in a footnote) that, in a shell function, ``declare foo="bar"`` creates a local variable and ``foo="bar"`` creates a global variable.

Comment: @G-Man Naturally you're very right indeed. Yet.. I don't know.. if this answer of mine has any little reason to exist among the other excellent ones by fra-san and Kusalananda is possibly because it handles only a couple of particular concepts in an (intentionally) overly rich way, though necessarily stripped of collateral details because otherwise it'd be even longer and tedious. A tale for absolute beginners, more than a proper description of what `declare` does. Perhaps your very comment, which I upvoted, may serve well as the footnote you mention ?

Answer (score 6):

In general, `declare` in the `bash` shell sets (or removes, or displays) *attributes* on variables.  An attribute is a sort of annotation that says "this is a name reference", or "this is an associative array", or "this variable should always be evaluated as an integer", or "this variable is read-only and can not be re-set", or "this variable is exported (an environment variable)" etc.

The `typeset` built-in is a synonym for `declare` in `bash`, as `typeset` is used in other shells (`ksh`, where it originated, and `zsh`, for example) for setting variable attributes.

---

Looking more closely at the name reference example in the question:

The shell function that you show, with an added bit of code that uses it:

```
#!/bin/bash

function read_and_verify  {
    read -p "Please enter value for '$1': " tmp1
    read -p "Please repeat the value to verify: " tmp2
    if [ "$tmp1" != "$tmp2" ]; then
        echo "Values unmatched. Please try again."; return 2
    else
        declare -n ref="$1"
        ref=$tmp1
    fi
}

read_and_verify foo
printf 'The variable "foo" has the value "%s"\n' "$foo"
```

Running this:

```
$ bash script.sh
Please enter value for 'foo': hello
Please repeat the value to verify: hello?
Values unmatched. Please try again.
The variable "foo" has the value ""
```

That shows that the `foo` variable is not being set to anything when the user inputs two *different* strings.

```
$ bash script.sh
Please enter value for 'foo': hello
Please repeat the value to verify: hello
The variable "foo" has the value "hello"
```

That shows that the variable `foo` gets set to the string that the user entered when they entered the *same* string twice.

The way that `$foo` gets the value `hello` in the main part of the script is by the following lines in the shell function:

```
declare -n ref="$1"
ref=$tmp1
```

where `$tmp1` is the string `hello` inputted by the user, and `$1` is the string `foo` passed in on the function's command line from the main part of the script.

Notice that the `ref` variable is declared with `declare -n` as a name reference variable and that the value `foo` is given as the value in that declaration.  This means that from that point on, until the variable passes out of scope, any use of the variable `ref` will be the same as using `foo`.  The variable `ref` is a *name reference variable* referencing `foo` at this point.

This has the consequence that assigning a value to `ref`, as is done on the line following the declaration, will assign the value to `foo`.

The value `hello` is then available in `$foo` in the main part of the script.

Answer (score 2):

Declare is one of a few syntaxes for declaring a variable in Bash:

```bash
x=7
declare x=7
declare x

function something {
  local x
  local x=7
}
```

These various ways of declaring variables are a consequence of the gradual evolution of shell.

The `-n` is a way of declaring what is sometimes called a "variable variable" -- it is a variable that is bonded to another variable. You can test out the following script [online](https://www.jdoodle.com/test-bash-shell-script-online/):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit -o nounset -o pipefail

declare thevariable
declare -n thevariablevariable=thevariable

thevariable='the value'

printf 'thevariable: %s\n' "$thevariable"
printf 'thevariablevariable: %s\n' "$thevariablevariable"

thevariablevariable='the other value'

printf 'thevariable: %s\n' "$thevariable"
printf 'thevariablevariable: %s\n' "$thevariablevariable"
```

What you see when you run it is that `thevariablevariable` is not a pointer to `thevariable`, rather it is an alias for `thevariable`:

```
thevariable: the value
thevariablevariable: the value
thevariable: the other value
thevariablevariable: the other value
```

Now this may seem like a devious misfeature and it is, indeed, an unusual language feature. However, shell programming sometimes requires strange features.

It may seem odd that we have so many ways of declaring variables in shell, which is notionally a very simple and lofi language; but it has to do with gradual changes in how we program. One example is function local variable definitions.

The simplest way to set a value is obviously `x=7`; but when we have a script with functions, what does the following mean?

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit -o nounset -o pipefail

x=7

function something {
  x=6
}

something

printf 'What is x? It is: %s\n' "$x"
```

Well, one reasonable interpretation is that `x` should still be `7` at the end of the script; but in fact it is 6, because there was a time when it was not the general expectation of programmers that declarations in functions were local. Experience has shown us that function locals are a good practice; but we can not simply change the meaning of declarations in shell because it will break all the old scripts. Therefore, we introduce a new declaration syntax.

Comment: I've never encountered `-n`. That sounds useful in theory (for a more semantic variable name than `$1` without duplicating it by value). I hope I remember to try it out next time.