# test -R True if the shell variable VAR is set and is a name reference

Tags: bash, variable, test

First I follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13219811/15603477) then I search about `test -v` then https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/testh.html shows that there is an `R` option.
`test -R` seems related to name preference.
Then I search **name reference**, Then I found out [What is a "name reference" variable-attribute?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/510715/what-is-a-name-reference-variable-attribute)
But I still not sure **named reference ** mean?

```
array1=([11]="triage" 51=["trajectory"] 129=["dynamic law"])

for i in 10 11 12 30 {50..51} {128..130}; do
        if [ -v 'array1[i]' ]; then
                echo "Variable 'array1[$i]' is defined"
        else 
                echo "Variable 'array1[$i]' not exist"
        fi
done
declare -n array1=$1
printf '\t%s\n' "${array1[@]}"

if [ -R 'array1' ]; then
        echo "Yes"
        else echo "no" 
fi
```

Since the last if block returns `no`, which means it's not a name reference.
then how to based on above code block to demo **named reference**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "name reference" variable is a variable that refers to another variable by name.

```bsh
$ foo='hello world'
$ declare -n bar=foo
$ echo "$bar"
hello world
$ bar='goodbye'
$ echo "$foo"
goodbye
```

```bsh
$ [[ -R foo ]] && echo nameref
$ [[ -R bar ]] && echo nameref
nameref
```

In the example above, the variable `foo` is ordinary while `bar` is a name reference variable, referring to the `foo` variable.  Accessing the value `$bar` accesses `$foo`, and setting `bar` sets `foo`.

Name references are useful in various ways, for example when passing arrays to a function:

```bsh
worker () {
    local -n tasks="$1"
    local -n hosts="$2"

    for host in "${hosts[@]}"; do
        for task in "${tasks[@]}"; do
            # run "$task" on "$host"
        done
    done
}

mytasks=( x y z )
myhosts=( a b c )

my_otherhosts=( k l m )

worker mytasks myhosts        # run my tasks on my hosts
worker mytasks my_otherhosts  # run my tasks on my other hosts
```

The `worker` function above receives two strings as arguments. These strings are names of arrays. By using `local` with `-n`, I declare both `tasks` and `hosts` as name reference variables, referring to the named variables.  As the variables whose name I pass to the function are arrays, I may use the name reference variables as arrays in the function.

The error in your code is that a name reference variable can not be an array, which is what your `array1` variable is, which is why you get `no` as the output from your `if` statement.  This error is also mentioned by the shell when you run your code:

```bsh
$ bash script
Variable 'array1[10]' not exist
Variable 'array1[11]' is defined
Variable 'array1[12]' is defined
Variable 'array1[30]' not exist
Variable 'array1[50]' not exist
Variable 'array1[51]' not exist
Variable 'array1[128]' not exist
Variable 'array1[129]' not exist
Variable 'array1[130]' not exist
script: line 10: declare: array1: reference variable cannot be an array
        triage
        51=[trajectory]
        129=[dynamic law]
no
```

You could have *another* variable refer to `array1`, though:

```bsh
declare -n array2=array1
```